# Is it possible to run `git commit --amend --no-edit` using the {gert} R package?

Tags: r, git

I would like to amend a commit using {gert} but did not find any function available to do this using the {gert} R package. Did I miss something? Is there an equivalent for `git commit --amend --no-edit` in the {gert} R package?

Comment: I think the answer is no, because that is handled by the `libgit2` function `git_commit_amend`, and that function is never called by `gert`.  Maybe you should submit an enhancement request or PR at https://github.com/r-lib/gert .